# Kotlin coroutine

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I try to understand how parent - child relationship works in that case

```
    private fun coroutineTest() {
        val job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val standAloneJob = Job(coroutineContext.job)//this will create the relationship parent - child
            launch(standAloneJob) {
                delay(2000)
                Log.d(TAG,"I'm here")
            }
            delay(4000)
            if(standAloneJob.isCompleted) { // always false
               Log.d(TAG,"isCompleted")
             }
            //standAloneJob.complete() // without this line method invokeOnCompletion never called
        }

        job.invokeOnCompletion {
            Log.d(TAG,"invokeOnCompletion")
        }

    }
```

The question is why child coroutine initialized by **standAloneJob** never completed and as a consequence parent coroutine not completed too?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to manually create a job in order to set up parent-child relationship. It's done by default when using `launch { .. }` without overriding its job.

If you do create your own job like this, it becomes your responsibility to complete it.

`standAloneJob` here only acts as a *parent* for the nested `launch`'s job, it's not the job of that launch:

```kotlin
val job = GlobalScope.launch {
    val standAloneJob = Job(coroutineContext.job)//this will create the relationship parent - child
    val child = launch(standAloneJob) {
        ...
    }
    println(child == standAloneJob) // false
    println(child in standAloneJob.children) // true
    ...
}
```

When the nested `launch` completes, its associated job is completed too, but it doesn't automatically complete its parent `standAloneJob` and thus it doesn't complete its grandparent `coroutineContext.job`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i know that i don't need create the Job. My question is theoretical. Why it doesn't complete in that case? Why child coroutine never switch to completed state?

Comment: Because you created the job yourself, so you're responsible for its lifecycle. If you start several coroutines with this job, how would you expect it to work? The first one would complete it? The last one?

Comment: actually, i expect the parent job will manage the child lifecycle. Because of the child job references to parent job val standAloneJob = Job(coroutineContext.job) standAloneJob == coroutineContext.job.children.first() will true

Comment: I don't understand how the true condition you mentioned is relevant. If you cancel the parent, the parent will cancel its children. If a child throws, the parent will be aware of it (and if it's not a `SupervisorJob` it will be cancelled and cancel its children). This is what you get from the parent-child relationship. The parent waits for children to complete. However, jobs don't complete on their own. The job associated to a coroutine will also be automatically completed when the coroutine ends, but the job you created yourself here is only the parent of the coroutine's job